# Expected value of pairs remaining after draw

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Problem:** Someone removed $m$ shoes from a pile with $n$ distinct pairs of shoes ($2n$ shoes total). Assuming that every shoe has an equal chance of $1/(2n)$ to be removed, what is the mean number of complete pairs of shoes to remain in the pile.

**Solutions:**
Defining $K$, a random variable denoting the number of shoes left in the pile, I argued that the probability of $k_i$ pairs of shoes remaining in the pile would be given by: 
\begin{align}
p_{k_i} & = \cfrac{{2n - 2k_i \choose m}}{2n \choose m} & \text{therefore,} \\
E(K) & = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n k\cfrac{{2n - 2k \choose m}}{2n \choose m}
\end{align}

However, I was given another solution, that defined the random variable $X$, such that, $x_i = 1$, when the $i$th pair remains in the pile. Then,
\begin{align}
p_{x_i = 1} & = \cfrac{{2n - 2 \choose m}}{2n \choose m} & \text{and,} \\
E(X) & = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\cfrac{{2n - 2 \choose m}}{2n \choose m} \\
& = n\cfrac{{2n - 2 \choose m}}{2n \choose m}
\end{align}

Are either solution correct? And most importantly, why?

**Edit** With some real numbers, it appears the second answer is correct, but I still do not understand the reasoning (or the error in reasoning for the first proposed answer).

```
ans1 <- function(n, m) {
  sum(sapply(1:n, function(k) k*choose(2*n - 2*k, m)/choose(2*n, m)))
}
ans2 <- function(n, m) {
  n*choose(2*n - 2, m)/choose(2*n, m)
}
list('ans1' = ans1(10, 4), 'ans2' = ans2(10, 4))
# $ans1
# [1] 2.73808
# 
# $ans2
# [1] 6.315789
```

Clearly, if we remove 4 shoes, the maximum number of pairs destroyed is 4, so an expected value less than 6 is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter solution appears largely correct. To be clear, if $X_{i}=1$ if the $i$th pair of shoes remains after the selection, and is 0 otherwise, then $X_{i}\sim$Bernoulli($p$), where $p=\binom{2n-2}{m}/\binom{2n}{m}$. Then $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i},$ so $E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(X_{i})=np.$ Note that despite the similarity in computation, $X$ is *not* Binomial, however, since the $X_{i}$ are not independent.

One problem with the first solution is that you're saying that the probability of $k_{i}$ pairs of shoes remaining is $\binom{2n-2k_{i}}{m}/\binom{2n}{m},$ so the numerator is essentially counting the number of ways to select $m$ shoes from the $2n-2k_{i}$ shoes left over, given that $k_{i}$ pairs are left intact. But this does not account for the fact that there are multiple ways to select the $k_{i}$ pairs from the $n$ possible. To see an example, suppose we have shoes labeled $1,2,3,4,$ with $1,2$ being a pair, and $3,4$ being a pair. Then if $k_{i}=1,$ $m=1$, then $\binom{4-2}{1}=2$, as you have counted. But we may remove any of the four shoes, and exactly one pair will remain, so the correct number should be $4=\binom{2}{1}\binom{4-2}{1}$.

Comment: My biggest confusion is how we can consider the probability of any single pair remaining in the pile, because my gut said that the probability of $k$ pairs remaining would be less than the probability of 1 pair remaining.

Comment: Consider this, however: in the above, if you remove $1$ shoe, you're guaranteed to have one pair remaining. If you remove $2$ shoes, then there are $2\times 2=4$ ways to have no pairs remaining, and $2$ ways to have $1$ pair remaining. If we remove $3$ or more shoes, we know there can be no pairs remaining. The possibilities and probabilities will change significantly depending on the relationships between $n,$ $m,$ and $k.$

Comment: When you have dependencies among different events, and you're mostly interested in the number of events that occur (here, the number of complete pairs remaining), using indicator random variables as has been done here is a standard trick, since linearity of expectation allows you to avoid all of the messy dependencies.

Comment: Apparently I need to do some reading on linearity of expectation.

Comment: I think until you've seen it used once, the technique doesn't necessarily come to mind, but now if you see a similar problem, you can use this idea. Definitely do that: linearity of expectation is incredibly important.

Answer (score 2):

The second formula is correct, easier to see via Linearity of Expectation.

Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ pair.  Thus, $X_i=1$ if the pair remains in the pile, and it $=0$ otherwise.

We remark that $$E_m[X_i]=\frac {2n-m}{2n}\times \frac {2n-m-1}{2n-1}$$  By Linearity we have your answer as $$E_m=nE_m[X_i]=\frac {(2n-m)(2n-m-1)}{2(2n-1)}$$

Note that this is equivalent to the second formula you provide.

As a crude Sanity Check we note that $$E_0=n \quad \&\quad  E_1=n-1$$
as expected.

Comment: Just pointing out that the probability ($E[X_{i}]$) that @lulu obtained is the same as the one in the second solution in the original question, in case there was any confusion about this for anyone.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet  Yes, thanks for stressing that.

Comment: I could see that your answer equated to the second one, and I really appreciate your input, but I would be more helped with some more justification. As I commented on the other answer, I do not understand how only considering the probability of a single pair remaining gives us the right answer.

Comment: I can see from @RideTheWavelet why the first answer is incorrect, but still would not get to the second answer on my own (which is really my goal).

Comment: Do you understand about Linearity of Expectation?  It's one of the great results from basic probability, not intuitive at all. It says that $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ even if $X,Y$ are dependent variables.  That's what I use here.

Comment: In this case, I note that $E=E[\sum X_i]$ which is obvious, no?  Then use Linearity to say that $E[\sum X_i]=\sum E[X_i]$ even though the $X_i$ are obviously dependent.